# Create cpio file with different absolute directory

Tags: u-boot, cpio

I am trying to modify a file system image packed with `cpio`. For that reason I first need to extract and later pack the image. As the image contains a whole file system all the files are given in absolute file names, so I can't directly pack and unpack it, since it would conflict with my machine's root system.

So when unpacking I used `--no-absolute-filenames` to unpack it to a working directory of my choice. Now I want to pack it again. If I just pack it i'd only get files like that:

```
/path/to/working/directory/file1
/path/to/working/directory/file2
/path/to/working/directory/file3
```

or

```
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

instead of

```
/file1
/file2
/file3
```

Does anyone know how I could get the desired output? Google didn't help me so far.

I really need absolute path names in the output file, because I am using it for an u-boot uImage file system image, and that requires the paths to be absolute, or it won't boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) and its `-s` option to rename files as they are added to the archive. Pax is POSIX's replacement for the traditional utilities `tar` and `cpio`; some Linux distributions don't install it by default but it should always be available as a package.

```
pax -w -x cpio -s '~^[/]*~~' root-directory >archive.cpio
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have python and:

- install [libarchive-c](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive-c) (e.g. using `pip install libarchive-c`)
- have all your files under directory `root` in the current directory ( I used
  `mkdir -p root/xyz ; echo 1 > root/abc.txt ; echo 2> root/xyz/def.txt` )
- save the following as `abscpio` and make it executable (`chmod 755 abscpio`)

  ```
  #! /usr/bin/env python
  import os
  import sys
  from libarchive import ffi
  from libarchive.write import (
     new_archive_write, ArchiveWrite, new_archive_read_disk)
  from libarchive.entry import new_archive_entry, ArchiveEntry
  from libarchive.ffi import (
      ARCHIVE_EOF,
      entry_sourcepath,
      entry_clear,
      read_next_header2,
      read_disk_descend,
      write_header,
      write_data,
      write_finish_entry,
  )


  class AbsArchiveWrite(ArchiveWrite):

     def add_abs_file(self, path, store_path):
        """Read the given paths from disk and add them to the archive.
        """
        write_p = self._pointer

        block_size = ffi.write_get_bytes_per_block(write_p)
        if block_size <= 0:
           block_size = 10240  # pragma: no cover

        with new_archive_entry() as entry_p:
           entry = ArchiveEntry(None, entry_p)
           with new_archive_read_disk(path) as read_p:
              while 1:
                 r = read_next_header2(read_p, entry_p)
                 if r == ARCHIVE_EOF:
                    break
                 entry.pathname = store_path
                 read_disk_descend(read_p)
                 write_header(write_p, entry_p)
                 try:
                    with open(entry_sourcepath(entry_p), 'rb') as f:
                       while 1:
                          data = f.read(block_size)
                          if not data:
                             break
                          write_data(write_p, data, len(data))
                 except IOError as e:
                    if e.errno != 21:
                       raise  # pragma: no cover
                 write_finish_entry(write_p)
                 entry_clear(entry_p)
                 if os.path.isdir(path):
                    break


  base_dir = sys.argv[2]

  with new_archive_write('cpio', None) as archive_p:
     ffi.write_open_filename_w(archive_p, sys.argv[1])
     a = AbsArchiveWrite(archive_p)

     for root, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(base_dir):
        for dir_name in dir_names:
           full_name = os.path.join(root, dir_name)
           a.add_abs_file(full_name, full_name.replace(base_dir, '/', 1))
        for file_name in file_names:
           full_name = os.path.join(root, file_name)
           a.add_abs_file(full_name, full_name.replace(base_dir, '/', 1))

  print '----- listing ' + sys.argv[1]
  os.system('cpio -itv -I ' + sys.argv[1])
  ```

you can do:

```
abscpio my_arch.cpio root/
```

with as output something similar to:

```
----- listing my_arch.cpio
drwxrwxr-x   2 anthon   users           0 Jun 25 18:59 /xyz
-rw-rw-r--   1 anthon   users           2 Jun 25 18:59 /abc.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 anthon   users           0 Jun 25 18:59 /xyz/def.txt
```

for production you might want to delete the last two lines from the script.

Links are stored as well, but I haven't tried other "file" types.